# Downloading source files cache modernizr.load.1.5.4.js Grunt Build Stall

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I have been using Yeoman to start building with web apps and such for maybe the last month. And I have been running into some issues  and have been able to resolve most of them. However, now I am stuck.
I'm running MAC OS 10.6.8

I have reinstalled Yeoman and Node fixed my paths for (what I know) as global.

Running grunt in my app.

1. Forces me to run as    `sudo`. (I think this is because this OS has password protected permissions for apps and programs to install/modify files.
   ** If I run    `grunt -f`
    
   `Warning: Unable to write "dist/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js" file (Error code: EACCES).` This error happens with most of the main tasks in grunt.
2. Running `sudo grunt`
   grunt runs through the tasks just fine until the real issue I cannot locate an answer.

   `Running "modernizr" task`

   Enabled Extras

   > > shiv
   > >     load
   > >     cssclasses

   Looking for Modernizr references

   in dist/styles/main.css

   > > svg
   > >     input

   Downloading source files

   cache modernizr.load.1.5.4.js

---

And grunt will not finish this download of source files. When I ran grunt using    `force` it would complete the download.
 I am looking for a solution for the 2nd list item. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that there some glitch in the npm grunt-modernizr.

I used this code:
`npm remove grunt-moderizr && npm install --save-dev grunt-modernizr`
found here: https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/48

Comment: that should be `npm remove grunt-modernizer` right?

Comment: sorry yes, remove `grunt-modernizer @HarryMoreno